# Can smb help out how to sum adjacent non-blank cells, and get the outcomes of clustered (grouped) cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Quantity*
Price

```
10  =SUM(E5:E8)
11  
12  
13  


16  =SUM(E11:E16)
17  
18  
19  
20  
21  


20  =SUM(E19:E20)
21




25  =SUM(E23:E27)
26  
27  
28  
29
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Formula in `F5`:

```
=IF(AND(E4="",E5<>""),SUM(E5:INDEX(E:E,MIN(IF(E5:$E$28="",ROW(E5:$E$28))))),"")
```

Enter as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>